# Is there a way to query a specific middle part of a firestore collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to be able to only read documents from a query somewhere in the middle of a query instead of just using `limit` or `limitToLast` to get one end. Ex; A way to get documents 10-20 categorized by a server timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Firestore doesn't offer any index-based filtering of query results.  Those queries do not scale in the way that Firestore requires.  Your option for skipping through results is limited to cursor-based queries that let you start at the beginning query results, and paginate through them, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).